# Trouble building a library

Tags: c, makefile, configuration-files

I am having a lot of trouble compiling a library. The library is ESFlib available on [this](http://hogwarts.ucsd.edu/~pkrysl/software.html) page. It is dependent on the Mescach and Ckit libraries, both of which can be found on the previously linked webpage. I have no issues building the Ckit library, however I do encounter some issues with the Meschach library, which has some issues relating to a file named zmachine. Despite this I have managed to build a mesach.a library file using the rebuild.sh file. However, when I try to build the ESFlib file I get a internal compiler error.

I am using a virtual box machine with Ubuntu 64, if this is at all relevant.  I am quite new to this sort of stuff so any help would be much appreciated as the contents of this library would save me a lot of time !

Regards, 
Stephen

Results of ./configure and make

```
./configure
"\n            Note: \n        configure can be run with the option --enable-SECOND_DERIVATIVES=t\n        to build the ESFLIB version which supports second derivatives.\n"
"\n            Note: \n        configure can be run with the option --enable-WRAP_AROUND=t\n        to build the ESFLIB version which supports the wrap-around \n        \(diffraction\) method of weight function smoothing at crack tips.\n"
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gcc... yes
checking compile with prototypes... yes (gcc )
checking preprocessor... gcc  -E  
checking for _get_list_next in -lckit... yes
checking ckitcfg.h usability... yes
checking ckitcfg.h presence... yes
checking for ckitcfg.h... yes
checking for LUfactor in -lmeschach... no
checking /home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src/../../Meschach/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libmeschach.a... no
checking /home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src/../../Meschach/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/meschach.a... checking /home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src/../../Meschach/libmeschach.a... no
checking /home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src/../../Meschach/meschach.a... yes
checking matrix2.h usability... yes
checking matrix2.h presence... yes
checking for matrix2.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for random... yes
checking for rand... yes
checking for isnan... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

make
arch=`./config.guess`; arch=`config.sub $arch`; \
if test "xx86_64-pc-linux-gnu" != "x$arch" ; then \
    make reconfigure; \
fi
/bin/sh: 1: config.sub: not found
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
make clean; ./configure
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
for n in 1 2 3 ; do \
        make SPDIM=$n ESFLIB_LANG="" clean_${n}d; \
        make SPDIM=$n ESFLIB_LANG=f  clean_${n}d; \
done
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Cleaning build files
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Cleaning build files
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Cleaning build files
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Cleaning build files
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Cleaning build files
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Cleaning build files
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
"\n            Note: \n        configure can be run with the option --enable-SECOND_DERIVATIVES=t\n        to build the ESFLIB version which supports second derivatives.\n"
"\n            Note: \n        configure can be run with the option --enable-WRAP_AROUND=t\n        to build the ESFLIB version which supports the wrap-around \n        \(diffraction\) method of weight function smoothing at crack tips.\n"
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gcc... yes
checking compile with prototypes... yes (gcc )
checking preprocessor... gcc  -E  
checking for _get_list_next in -lckit... yes
checking ckitcfg.h usability... yes
checking ckitcfg.h presence... yes
checking for ckitcfg.h... yes
checking for LUfactor in -lmeschach... no
checking /home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src/../../Meschach/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libmeschach.a... no
checking /home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src/../../Meschach/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/meschach.a... checking /home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src/../../Meschach/libmeschach.a... no
checking /home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src/../../Meschach/meschach.a... yes
checking matrix2.h usability... yes
checking matrix2.h presence... yes
checking for matrix2.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for random... yes
checking for rand... yes
checking for isnan... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Removing dim dependent files
make SPDIM=1 make_1d
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Running make for dim=1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Creating esflibtop.h from template
Creating esflib1.h
Compiling sf.c
In file included from sf.c:19:0:
esflibpriv.h:1:0: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 #ifndef ESFLIBPRIV_H
 ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Makefile:203: recipe for target 'sf.o' failed
make[2]: *** [sf.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Makefile:112: recipe for target 'make_c1d' failed
make[1]: *** [make_c1d] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/stephen/Documents/ESFLib/src'
Makefile:100: recipe for target '1d' failed
make: *** [1d] Error 2
```

Comment: The libraries are 15+ years old, could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen gcc crash when it has run out of memory - increase the memory on your virtualbox instance and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I increased the memory to 12gb but I still face the same issue.

Comment: I was having issues with some compiling at 16Gb and increased to 32

Comment: Hmmf , I'm all out of ram , I'll have to try it on another PC when I get the chance .